# How to tansform ${\sqrt{n-1}} + {\sqrt{n+1}} = q$ into $q^4 - 4q^2n + 4 = 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please help me tansform ${\sqrt{n-1}} + {\sqrt{n+1}} = q$ into $q^4 - 4q^2n + 4 = 0$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that
$$
\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n+1}=\frac{(n+1)-(n-1)}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}}=
\frac{2}{\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}}
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n-1}=\frac{2}{q}
$$
Summing with the original equation, you get
$$
2\sqrt{n+1}=q+\frac{2}{q}
$$
Now square both sides and simplify.

Alternatively, rewrite as
$$
\sqrt{n-1}=q-\sqrt{n+1}
$$
and square:
$$
n-1=q^2-2q\sqrt{n+1}+n+1
$$
so
$$
2q\sqrt{n+1}=q^2+2
$$
Square again.

Answer (score 0):

Squaring both sides, you get
$$2n+2\sqrt{n^2-1}=q^2\iff (q^2-2n)^2=4(n^2-1)\iff q^4-4nq^2+4n^2=4n^2-4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, just **do** the calculations indicated!  With $q= \sqrt{n- 1}+ \sqrt{n+ 1}$, $q^2= (\sqrt{n- 1})^2+ 2\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}+ (\sqrt{n+ 1})^2= n- 1+ 2\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}+ n+ 1= 2n+ 2\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}$ and then $q^4= 4(n^2+ 2n\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}+ (n-1)(n+ 1))= 4(n^2+ 2n\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}+ n^2- 1)= 4(2n^2+ 2n\sqrt{n-1}\sqrt{n+1}- 1)$

$-4nq^2= -8n^2- 8n\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}$ so $q^4- 4nq^2= 8n^2+ 8n\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}- 4- 8n^2- 8n\sqrt{n- 1}\sqrt{n+ 1}= -4$